# How to get YQL to only return new content (based on a given date)

Tags: xml, rss, yql

Need to know how to get YQL to return only data that's newer than a date that I specify.

Thanks

Comment: Please ask a question. Reference: http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html

Comment: Thanks Alex Trebec.  Take that as sarcastically as possible.  How do I get YQL to filter the newest results based on date that I specify?  What function would I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the Data Table you are querying and the web service that's behind it.

For example, facebook graph allows you to set a `since` query parameter, and you can map a `key` on it on your Data Table.

```
http://graph.facebook.com/search?q=watermelon&since=yesterday
```

If not, filter on the `date` element in you results

```
SELECT * from foo.table WHERE date > "2011-03-11T14:00"

<results>
    <post>
        <title>My title</title>
        <link>my link</link>
        <author>fooman</author>
        <date>2011-03-11T14:09</date>
        <content>lorem ipsum</content>
    </post>
    <post>
        <title>My title</title>
        <link>my link</link>
        <author>fooman</author>
        <date>2011-03-11T15:09</date>
        <content>lorem ipsum</content>
    </post>
</results>
```

This should work, provided that your dates are formatted in a way that makes alphabetical ordering equivalent to temporal order.

If your query is something like

```
select title,source,description,date from rss where url in ('somerssfeed.com';, 'somerssfeed.com';) | unique(field="title") | sort(field="date", descending="true")
```

put the filter before the pipes:

```
select title,source,description,date from rss where url in ('somerssfeed.com';, 'somerssfeed.com';) and date > "2010-01-01T00:00" | unique(... [snip!]
```

Comment: Thanks rjack.  Not sure where to insert the date filter in my query.  `code` select title,source,description,date from rss where url in (
    'http://somerssfeed.com',
    'http://somerssfeed.com'
) | unique(field="title") | sort(field="date", descending="true")